# Exporting/Downloading CSV on the fly using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download, dynamically-generated

I am wondering what is the best way to tackle the following problem. I need to provide a client with the option to download various ranges of records from a database in CSV format. I was thinking of doing the following.

1. Provide user with a webform to determine what rows to pull from the DB.
2. Pull the appropriate records and create a large string from the return data.
3. Post the string to the script which creates the CSV for downloading.

Before I attempt the above I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) to immediately obtain your results in a CSV.  You then need only read the contents of that CSV file back to the user.

This is much safer than attempting to construct a CSV yourself (where you must consider how to properly escape field delimiters, etc); however, if you wanted to do it that way, I'd recommend using [`fputcsv(STDOUT, $results)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to avoid common pitfalls.

Comment: I like the idea of being able to do it straight from mysql, how would you prompt the user to then download the resulting file though?

Comment: Your PHP script that handles the user's form submission could just call [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) on the file outputted by MySQL.  Remember to set MIME type appropriately (`text/csv`) and, if you want to force the browser to prompt to save the file rather than just displaying it in the window, also set `Content-disposition: attachment;filename=foo.csv`.

Comment: Smashing i think i'll give this a bash. Thanks ^_^